# how to upload opencart extension of opencart official extesnion directory

Tags: php, opencart

I've developed an extension of opencart. Now I want to upload that extension on the official opencart site (extension directory) but don't know that how to do that. Can anyone please help me. Its my first time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an account on their official site - [www.opencart.com](https://www.opencart.com).
2. Go to account page. You will get option **Manage extensions**.
3. Fill required details and upload your extension using above option.
4. Done!!

Comment: Thanks @Monika...you answer helped me